# result is wrong when retrieving the date

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm working with PostgreSQL. I have two database tables,i want to get the min and max date stored in table1 daterange column which is of type character varying. table1 and table2 is mapped using sid. i want to get the max and min date range of table1 when compared with sid of table2. Please find the demo [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.5&fiddle=e668813955ddb7455eb5c533298720bb). The result is wrong.

table1:

```
sid  daterange  

100  5/25/2017
101  1/24/2017
102  4/4/2014
103  11/12/2007
104  4/24/2012
105  01/15/2017
106  1/1/2017
107  3/11/2016
108  10/10/2001
109  1/10/2016
110  12/12/2016
111  4/24/2017
112  06/28/2015
113  5/24/2017
114  5/22/2017
```

table2:

```
sid  description

100  success
101  pending
104  pending
105  success
106  success
107  success
110  success
111  pending
112  failed
113  failed
114  pending
```

Below is my query:

```
select min(daterange) as minDate,max(daterange) as maxDate from (SELECT to_date(table1.daterange, 'DD/MM/YYYY') as daterange FROM table1,table2 where 
      table1.sid = table2.sid) tt;
```

The result is as below which is wrong(mindate and  maxdate displayed are wrong dates).

```
mindate     maxdate
2013-12-07  2019-01-07
```

Please advice. daterange column in table1 is of type character varying.I cannot use `::date` to convert to date type, because i need to use this query in my java hibernate code and the java code is not recognizing `::`

Comment: Why the result is wrong...do you want one result for every sid?

Comment: no..i mean the min and max dates its showing is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have day and month mixed up in the date format string. 
Should be 
to_date(table1.daterange, 'MM/DD/YYYY')